# How to appropriately use pointers in C++ functions?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, pointers, pre-increment

I'm trying to get the hang of pointers and addresses in C++ and am having trouble with functions with changing parameters.

The code below is writing `Loop run #1.` in an infinite loop, instead of incrementing the value `foo`.

My question is: **What is the issue with this code here?**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void Statement(int *foo) {
    std::cout << "Loop run #" << *foo << ". ";
    foo++;
}

int main() {

    int foo = 1;

    for (;;) {
        Statement(&foo);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the code doing? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with functions. It would be the same if all the code was inside main.

Comment: Dis you mean to write `(*foo)++;` inside the function?

Comment: You are incrementing a copy of a pointer, not the integer being pointed to

Comment: In `c++` its better to pass by reference instead of by pointer like you would have if you were writing `c` code.

Comment: Thank you to πάντα ῥεῖ and AndyF for clearing up the mishap :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I ran the code through and it works just fine. The goal expressed in the post has been reached with both your and Sombrero's/Paul's methods. Thanks for the help in any case!

Comment: @maxxy Oh, I am sorry. I thought that you are returning the expression ( *foo )++.:)

Comment: @maxxy Regarding your question as posted. _**"What is the issue with this code here?"**_ Isn't a clear statement about the problem you have. Always explain clearly what you expected from the (also clearly specified) inputs and outputs you see. In other word's post a [mcve], this is the minimum required for well received questions here.

Comment: I'll take care to be more descriptive and detailed with my questions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're incrementing a copy of the pointer itself, not what it points to. You probably meant:

```
(*foo)++;
```

This still won't fix the infinite loop though because you have nothing to stop it with.

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is that you're incrementing the pointer, not the pointed-to data.

replace

```
foo++
```

with

```
(*foo)++
```

to increment the pointed-to value.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly what you are trying to do then the function should be declared the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

void Statement(int *foo) {
    std::cout << "Loop run #" << *foo << ". ";
    ++*foo;
}

int main() {

    int foo = 1;

    for (; ; ) {
        Statement(&foo);
    }
}
```

That is in an infinite loop you are trying to output incremented value of `foo`.

In this case you have increment the value itself pointed to by the pointer like

```
++*foo
```

If you want to limit loop iterations then you can use for example an object of the type unsigned char and define the loop the following way

```
#include <iostream>

void Statement( unsigned char *foo) {
    std::cout << "Loop run #" << int( *foo ) << ". ";
    ++*foo;
}

int main() {

    unsigned char foo = 1;

    for (; foo ; ) {
        Statement(&foo);
    }
}
```